# Android Studio - Cannot remove a submenu from NavigationView

Tags: android

I want to **remove a specific group** from my [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) that is part of my [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)

I have tried using the following lines of code that I found on stack to remove the group, but **it doesnt work**.

**1). Removing group by ID**

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
menu.removeGroup(R.id.myPagesGroup);
```

**2). Setting visibility by ID**

```
menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.myPagesGroup, false);
```

**3). Finding submenu from first another group item to then set visibility**

```
menu.findItem(R.id.nav_support).getSubMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.myPagesGroup, false);
```

Code snippet **1** and **2** does not give me an error, the group is just visible.

Snippet **3** gives me a [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.SubMenu.setGroupVisible(int, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Removing an item by using the code below **does work** however.

```
menu.removeItem(R.id.nav_calendar);
```

Below is the actual **Menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/favoritesGroup"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_calendar"
        android:title="Kalender"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_none"
        android:title=""
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_availabilityList"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_calendar"
        android:title="Tillgänglighet"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_available_jobs"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment"
        android:title="Lediga Jobb"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_my_contacts"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:title="Kontakt"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_contactSc"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:title="Kontakt"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_support"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:title="Support"/>
</group>

<item android:title="Mina Sidor">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/myPagesGroup"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_commissions"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_commissions"
                android:title="Mina Uppdrag"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_commission_schedule"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_commission_schedule"
                android:title="Uppdragsschema"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_vacation"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_vacation_application"
                android:title="Semesteransökan"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_employment_terms"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_employment_terms"
                android:title="Anställningsvillkor"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_document"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_document"
                android:title="Dokument"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_consultant_agent"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_consultant_agent"
                android:title="Konsultombud"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_file_upload"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_file_upload"
                android:title="Ladda upp intyg"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_tests"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tests"
                android:title="Mina tester"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_matching_jobs"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_matching_jobs"
                android:title="Matchande jobb"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_applications"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_applications"
                android:title="Mina ansökningar"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_profile"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_profile"
                android:title="Min profil"/>
        </group>
    </menu>

</item>

<item android:title="Övrigt">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/generalGroup"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_looking_for_job"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment"
                android:title="Söker du jobb?"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_looking_for_personel"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_people"
                android:title="Söker du personal?"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_office"
                android:title="Om oss"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_phone"
                android:title="Logga ut"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>


</menu>
```

Comment: The menu that you are trying to remove is from the navigation view?

Comment: I tried to remove the group in the menu with id "myPageGroup", and the menu is part of the NavigationView which is part of my DrawerLayout

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this??

```
Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.myPagesGroup).setVisible(false);
```

And for groups

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.myPagesGroup, false);
```

Comment: the first solution gives me a nullpointer exception

the second one does not give me an error but it doesnt make the group invisible either

Comment: Its because first one is for single items

Comment: Yeah I used that one for removing individual items and it worked fine, but I couldnt remove the group from what I've tried. However, I just made a seperate menu and called menu.clear(); and navigationView.inflateMenu(r.menu.myMenu);